# Webpack error : output filename not configured

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, module, webpack

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app-client.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: ['babel-loader'],
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      mangle: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      beautify: false,
      dead_code: true
    })
  ]
};
```

I have checked the filename is  `webpack.config.js`.

File is in root directory of project.

It has `module.exports`.

So what could possibly go wrong ?

Error is showing `output filename not configured` when running

`NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p`

current directory is root project `/myproject$`

### *UPDATE*

Its solved

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes around . this error happened because i had no `/js/` folder inside `/src/`. Looks like webpack dosent creates folders. So after i created the folder using `mkdir` it worked smooth.